# How to get an OnPropertyChanged event to exectue before the current event continues

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void Build_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        T.BuildStatus = "Building...";            
        BuildSelected(T.ListofTrucks);                  
        T.BuildStatus = "Build Complete";
    }
```

Currently I have a label binded to T.BuildStatus that I want to display "Building..." while my files are compiled but the label will only update after buildSelected method has finished. How can I get this label to update before continuing with the rest of the event call?

Edit: the object T is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged correctly

Comment: Step 1: Go MVVM and forget about your WinForms background.

Comment: @HristoYankov I don't see any indication that they haven't...

Comment: I am using MVVM, I think that the event to update BuildStatus is being delayed until the button event completes.

Comment: `BuildSelected(T.ListofTrucks);` looks as though it's being called on your UI thread blocking any and all UI updates. If its CPU bound kick it off the UI thread with `Task.Run` or make it `async` if its IO bound.

Comment: @JSteward Could you explain a little more how to do that? I haven't done threading in wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `BuildSelected(T.ListofTrucks);` is CPU bound work. If it's called on the UI thread it will block `INotify` updates, i.e. since the UI thread is busy it can't update. Easiest fix:

```
private async void Build_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    T.BuildStatus = "Building...";            
    await Task.Run(() => BuildSelected(T.ListofTrucks));                  
    T.BuildStatus = "Build Complete";
}
```

Or if an IO operation:

```
private async void Build_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    T.BuildStatus = "Building...";            
    await BuildSelectedAsync(T.ListofTrucks));                  
    T.BuildStatus = "Build Complete";
}
```

`async Task BuildSelectedAsync(ListofTrucks x)` implementation will vary depending on the IO operation and what you're exactly doing.

Comment: Thanks you this worked great!